# by pass authorization to access google drive

Tags: google-oauth

I am shared folder in which does contain nearly 7 other folders. i have got client id and secret key and API key. i want to show all that folder in my application. if i m logged in to google drive.it works as soon i logged out it doesn't work, how can i by pass login screen

```
function handleClientLoad() {
            //console.log(gapi.client);
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            //checkAuth();
            //makeApiCall();
            //getFoldersList();
            window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
        }


    function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true }, handleAuthResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive data is private data it is owned by you and your account.  In order for your script to access that data you need to give it permissions to see that data.   This is the consent screen you are giving it permission to view the data.   Short of possibly setting the Google Drive folder to public and then using a public API key to access drive instead of Oauth2.

There are work abounds but none of them work with JavaScript.  If this is the only account you will be accessing I recommend you look into a server sided language like PHP or python and use a Service account.  You will have to give the service account access to your google drive by sharing the folders in question with it.  This is how service accounts are preauthorized.

Answer: There is no way to do away with the consent screen in JavaScript.  Or save your authentication for lager use (Refresh token).  Switch to a server sided language.

Comment: can you show an example with public api key ? and where can i find public api key(server key or browser key)